Compling org-mode citation in Latex table?
I exporting a table from R source block in Org-mode which is ready for Latex to compile. This table contains some citation keys in cells:
#+begin_src R :results output :wrap exports latex
  options(tidyverse.quiet=TRUE)
  library("tidyverse")
  library("kableExtra")
  library("xtable")
  options(kableExtra.auto_format = FALSE)

  df <- data.frame(citation = c("[cite:@cite1]", "[cite:@cite2]"),
           vara = c("va1", "va2"),
           varb = c("vb1", "vb2"))
  df |>
    xtable() |> 
    print.xtable(sanitize.text.function = identity,
         comment = FALSE,
         only.contents = FALSE)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_exports latex
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlll}
  \hline
 & citation & vara & varb \\ 
  \hline
1 & [cite:@cite1] & va1 & vb1 \\ 
  2 & [cite:@cite2] & va2 & vb2 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
#+end_exports

In this way I can get the compiled Latex table, but the citations won't be compiled;

or, I can do it that way:
#+begin_src R :results output :wrap exports org
  df <- data.frame(citation = c("[cite:@cite1]", "[cite:@cite2]"),
           vara = c("va1", "va2"),
           varb = c("vb1", "vb2"))
  df |>
    xtable::xtable() |> 
    knitr::kable(format = "markdown", booktabs = T)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_exports org


|citation      |vara |varb |
|:-------------|:----|:----|
|[cite:@cite1] |va1  |vb1  |
|[cite:@cite2] |va2  |vb2  |
#+end_exports

In this table, citations can be complied but the horizonal line is ruined.

So my question is, is there a way to keep the table and let the citations work as normal? I know I kinda trying to run a language into another... but any possible help will be highly appriciated!

AFAIK you can't use markdown inside of latex environments like tabular or table. You could use the normal latex \cite macro instead of markdown.

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz . The problem is, this results need to be embedded into another bigger org file that uses citar and a .csl file to handle with citations. Turning into \cite wouldn't work in that case.
